# How to get each N element of array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of, for example 10 elements:

```
var Ar = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

And I need to make new array from current array by taken each second element for example -

```
var newAr = [1,3,5,7,9]
```

How can I do it in Swift?

Comment: Hi tePoloN, welcome to the site. This isn't a free code-writing service. We're here to help with concrete issues in real code. Show us what you tried and where you got stuck, and we can help from there.

Comment: Exactly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over all the indices, and if an odd number, append it to a `result` array.

Example:

```
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
var result = [Int]()

for index in arr.indices {
    if !index.isMultiple(of: 2) {
        result.append(arr[index])
    }
}

print(result)
```